# Find row with specified text quickly

Tags: c#, excel

Okay, So I have a very large excel sheet in which I need to find a row with a specified string of text. The size of this sheet is on the order of 10,000 rows. I am currently doing things like this:

```
    sheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;

  // FIND the tape id in column: __________
        int cellRow = 0;
        int x = 0;
        for (x = 1; x <= 1000000; x++)
        {
            if (sheet.Cells[43][x].text.Contains(tapeID))
            {
                cellRow = x;
                break;
            }
        }
```

The problem is that this goes on for quite some time....and therefore too slow for my needs. I tried to do the sheet.find() method but it was returning a whole bunch of cells that were wrong.....can somebody help me implement the sheet.find or tell me about a faster way to do this?

I implemented find like this:

```
        sheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;
           Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range currentFind = currentFind = sheet.Cells.Find(tapeID, Type.Missing,
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart, 
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext, false,
    Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

But when I look at whats inside with
string value = currentFind[0][0].Text

I get the wrong cell.....does excel use zero addressing here?...going to investigate

Comment: What did sheet.find() return? What value is 'tapeID'?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: The answer is that it does NOT use 0 addressing. It does return the right cell if I use [1][1] as the indexing array. Thanks for patience

Answer (score 0):

As depressing as this is, I was just using the wrong indexing for the find function. I am a little ashamed of this, so we'll just forget that it happened.

Cheers